# flutter stripe gives issues on some devices

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-stripe

I'm using
`flutter_stripe: ^9.5.0+1`
and

```
    void main() async {
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        Stripe.publishableKey = stripePublishableKey;
        await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
        runApp(const MainApp());
    }
```

This is main app start point

after working on stripe payment
when i build the app it gets installed on all devices but
doesn't open on some devices and stuck on black screen whereas it runs normally on some devices

I tried changing multiple configuration on manifest file and build.gradle file reading solution from stackoverflow. but nothing works

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs? Does this happen on Android phones or also on iOS phones?

Comment: I build the app and after installing to physical device the app stuck on blank screen on android though it works on some device and doesn't work on some 
and when i test removing the async await from the code snippet i've provided it works on all device but the stripe form doesn't appear on some devices 
I don't really know any other stuff as i'm new to flutter